# How to check same user has second times login using redux react native with example

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I need to navigation after a same user visits when logsIn to our app 2 times. Has anyone an opinion on how would be the best approach for this using redux react native with example because I am new in Redux.

here is my code,

```
export const userLogin = (data, navigation) => {
  return dispatch => {
    let headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    axios
      .post(`${Url}api/auth/login`, data, {headers: headers})
      .then(resp => {
        let response = resp.data;
        let verified = resp.data.user.isVerified;
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(response.user));
        dispatch(setAuthToken(response.access_token));
        dispatch(setLoader(false));
        if (verified) {
          navigation.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              routes: [{name: 'mainRoutes'}],
            }),
          );
        } else {
          navigation.navigate('confirmYourEmail', {email: data.email});
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const err = error;
        if (err.response) {
          showMessage(err.response.data.message);
        }
        dispatch(setLoader(false));
      });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set one flag in your user table as onboarded, based on that you can decide which screen to be shown and once they click skip or next-next-next change your onboarded state.
using this approach if user uninstall the app, still you have data that user have been onboarded, but in redux you won't be able to keep data if user uninstall and then install.
if you want to make user see onboarding screen every time they install the app, then you can use redux.

Comment: I could not understand.

Comment: In your backend --> user Database table add  one more row as onboarded(variable with boolean data type). once user gets with initial screen you can send Http request and then update the state, and when ever user will login again, you will also get onboarded variable based on that you can decide the naviagtion.

Comment: const INITIAL_STATE = {
loginAttempt:0,
};
const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionsType.SET_LOGIN_ATTEMPT:
      return {
        loginAttempt: ++state.loginAttempt
      } 
default:
      return state;
  }
};    

But could not incremented what's wrong.